# removing table from array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this code, adding works perfectly but removing is not triggering, it seems if is only firing else:

```
// variables for dynamic columns
    const productName = <Table.Column dataIndex="title" title="Product Name"/>
    const productPrice = <Table.Column
                        dataIndex = "status"
                        title = "Price"
                        sorter={(a: any, b: any) => a.status - b.status}
                        />
    const productOffers = <Table.Column
                        dataIndex = "createdAt"
                        title = "Offers"
                        sorter={(a: any, b: any) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt}
                        render={(value) => <DateField format="LLL" value={value} />}
                        />
    const productPriceVariation = <Table.Column
                        dataIndex = "createdAt"
                        title = "Price Variation"
                        sorter={(a: any, b: any) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt}
                        render={(value) => <DateField format="LLL" value={value} />}
                        />

    // on click event for dropdown menu
    const [dynamicColumns, setDynamic] = useState([productName, productPrice, productOffers, productPriceVariation])

    const removeElement = (element: any) => {
        setDynamic(prevState => {
          const updatedColumns = prevState.filter(column => column.props.dataIndex !== element.props.dataIndex);
          return updatedColumns;
        });
      };
      

    const addElement = (element: any) => {
    const updatedColumns = dynamicColumns.concat([element]);
    setDynamic(updatedColumns);
    };

    const onClick: MenuProps['onClick'] = ({key}) => {
    if (key == '1') {
        if (dynamicColumns.includes(productPrice)) {
        removeElement(productPrice);
        } else {
        addElement(productPrice);
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to remove column if it exists, so when key value is 1 if it s already in array I want to remove it.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very happy

Code works nice and adding is working, but for some reason removing part of if statement is not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put a ReactNode in state. Keep state as pure data. E.g. if you do this instead, you can easily add/remove to the array.

```
const [dynamicColumns, setDynamic] = useState(['productName', 'productPrice', 'productOffers', 'productPriceVariation'])
```

Then, you check it in your return statetement

```
return dynamicColumns.map(column => {
  if (column === 'productName') return productName; // or better yet, inline the JSX here.
  else if (column === 'productPrice') return productPrice;
// etc..
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice and solved the problem. Many thanks.